# Need Online Exam System in Asp .Net

Tags: asp.net

I want to create one Online Exam System where student can attend Exam and there will be options below(in radiobutton) which he/she can choose as answer by using Asp .Net. In this process, Next and Previous should be worked properly. Please suggest me some idea or Code in this Reference.

Thanks..

Comment: So you want an ASP.NET website, with a web page, in which web page you will have a label with a question text with associated radiobuttons (which I presume you would get from a question database), and two buttons (Next and Previuos) with an associated behaviour? If you don't know how to do these things, you should first start by seing some ASP.NET tutorials (just a little search on the internet should provide you with many examples). Your question is too broad.

Comment: Yeah Coral, I just want to do such online website page where for every question 4 options would be there and Next , Previous Buttons and finally 'Finish' Button to end the exam.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following are links from where you can get ideas for Online exam system.

http://onlineexam.codeplex.com/\

http://ooes.codeplex.com/